# Cannot access the API from the application controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

There is a notes site that has the ability to create notes. After entering a note, I access the API and pass the note model to put it into the database. But it doesn't work, on invocation it returns a code 400 and is not even logged into the API controller. Although exactly the same code in another controller created for testing works and the GET access also works. All paths and names are correct.
Application controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNote(string? NoteText, string? NoteTitle)
{
    //Plug
    NoteViewModel viewModel = new NoteViewModel()
    {
        ClientId = 1,
        NoteTypeId = 1,
        NoteText = NoteText,
        EditDate = DateTime.Now,
        NoteTitle = NoteTitle
    };
    string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(viewModel);
    StringContent content = new StringContent(data.ToLower(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsync(baseAddres + "/DailyNotes/CreateNote", content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Notes", new { clientId = 1});
    }
    return View();
}
```

API controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Note>> CreateNote(NoteViewModel note)
{
    try
    {
        if (note == null)
            return BadRequest("Cant be Null");
        await _dailyNotesRepository.CreateNote(note);
        return Ok(note);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

CreateNote

```
public async Task<Note> CreateNote(NoteViewModel note)
    {
            Note newNote = new Note()
            {
                ClientId = note.ClientId,
                NoteTypeId = note.NoteTypeId,
                NoteTitle = note.NoteTitle,
                NoteText = note.NoteText,
                EditDate = note.EditDate
            };
            var result = await _context.Notes.AddAsync(newNote);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return result.Entity;
    }
```

[image: Breakpoint on response]

Tried many things, all names and paths are correct

Comment: Both snippets are API controllers. A 400 response is a Bad Request. If the request fails vaildation, the request will fail without calling the action and the body will contain a standardised ProblemDetails response.  What's the actual HTTP response?

Comment: What's the actual definition of `NoteViewModel`? Are any properties non-nullable or Required?

Comment: BTW instead of manually serializing the object to JSON you could use [PostAsJsonAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-7.0), eg `var response=await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url,viewModel);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos NoteViewModel is the data I'm passing, in general it doesn't matter because whatever the data is I have to get to the API controller

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The exact same code created for testing in another controller works with any data

Comment: If that was the case, there wouldn't be any error. If you want people to help, post the missing code, the actual data, the *full* exception and, if possible, the full HTTP response. It would be better if you could post executable code that actually reproduces the problem. It can be just a few lines in a console application that calls `await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url,new NoteViewModel{ClientId=1, NoteTypeId=1,NoteText="blah",NoteTitle="blah", EditDate = DateTime.Now});`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've updated the post above and attached a photo

Comment: BTW *your own code* returns `return BadRequest(ex.Message);` in case of error. That's not helpful, in fact it's worse than not catching the exception at all. An exception at this point would be due to a bug in `_dailyNotesRepository.CreateNote`, not a bad request. The message won't help callers identify what's wrong and will expose sensitive information to possible malicious callers. The exception message doesn't include the inner exceptions and the call stack of the actual exception. At the very least log the exception and *rethrow it*.

Comment: Photos aren't useful. They can't be copied, compiled or tested. That screenshot doesn't contain the *contents* of the response at all

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do you want me to throw an internal exception?

Comment: You haven't posted `NoteViewModel`. Your code is throwing an internal exception but instead of logging it, it returns just part of that exception with the wrong status. If `NoteTitle` is non-nullable in the database your action will still return a 400 even though the real error is an internal exception.  Post enough code so *we* can reproduce the problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you so much, your comment 
await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url,new NoteViewModel{ClientId=1, NoteTypeId=1,NoteText="blah",NoteTitle="blah", EditDate = DateTime.Now});

Helped solve the problem, can you explain why it worked like that and the code that was there didn't work, even though it worked in another controller

Comment: If the *data* is different, it doesn't matter what controller worked and what didn't. Never mind that `other controller` is unclear - other application controller or other API controller? Were both controllers using the same DTO, same data?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Both application controllers used the same code but different data, in the other controller the data was random but despite this the breakpoint still triggered in the API controller. But it didn't work with the correct data in the controller I needed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Also, could you please leave a reply to the question so I can tag you.